# ATI proprietary drivers not working with an ATI Radeon HD 3400

Tags: 11.10, compiz, ati, radeon

I am using Lenovo Thinkpad laptop with ATI Radeon HD 3400 Series graphic card. I installed Ubuntu 11.10 64 bit today and tried to install proprietary drivers

1)Hence I installed proprietary drivers displayed on my system (through jockey) .Rebooted my system. Performance is better now but Still compiz is not working.

2)Then I tried the second driver available  - 'post-release-updates' but couldn't install due to some error. Hence I opened synaptic and installed fglrx-updates  and rebooted my system. Not much change and still compiz didnt work

3)Removed all these packages and downloaded the latest driver from ATI  http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English and installed it and rebooted my system. This is worse as I dnt get even launcher or dash this time - I guess I am forcefully logged in to Ubuntu 2-D . Still compiz is not working

Am I doing something silly here ? Is any one facing similar issues with ATI ? Please help
Thanks.

Comment: As a NVidia user, I only had to download the driver from NVidia.com and install it. Compiz and everything else work perfectly. I have avoided the proprietary drivers. It most likely is ATI/11.10 compatibility issues. Hope you get the problem fixed, no thanks to me though :)

Comment: Haha good for you. Yeah support for Nvidia is better than that of ATI :)

Comment: Depends on what you want! At least games on wine work nice on ATI, who cares about unity3d anyways!

Answer (score 1):

This is a good solid guide to getting the latest ATI driver installed in ubuntu.
http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Oneiric_Installation_Guide#Installing_Catalyst_Manually_.28from_AMD.2FATI.27s_site.29

Has some good troubleshooting tips too.

Answer (score 1):

If your BIOS supports switchable display it should be disabled in favor of discrete graphics adaptor. The drivers cannot handle switchable graphics.

Answer (score 0):

No, you're not alone. I also have problems with the ATI driver under 11.10 64bit.

I'm just guessing but I think this problem has to do with the way support for 32bit applications was added to the 64bit image.

I reverted to 11.04 and the ATI driver from amd.com works fine. I think we'll have to wait until the new release from ATI.

Comment: Instead of reverting back to 11.04, I am using open source drivers available by default with 11.10 and I have to say its cool enough :)

Comment: I agree, but I think that's only true for HD5xxx and upwards.

Answer (score 0):

I posted [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67065/system-doesnt-boot-after-amd-11-9-driver-install/67169#67169) on a similar question.

To expand on duffydack's answer (which I followed also) I first [purged](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem:_Need_to_purge_-fglrx) the system of fglrx in recovery, after remounting and dropping into netroot.

Comment: did it work for you?

Comment: Yes, perfectly. Currently don't have any issues. Though I am using HD57xx card.

Answer (score 0):

ATI just released the 11.11 drivers 
Here's the link
http://support.amd.com/us/gpudownload/linux/Pages/radeon_linux.aspx?type=2.4.1&product=2.4.1.3.42&lang=English

Comment: Thanks ... Has Any one tried this? I would be very happy to see it working :)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a quick and dirty guide to installing proprietary drivers for Nvidia 8400GS video card. Also this tutorial will work for any other type of proprietary driver you need to install. [Proprietary Drivers Ubuntu](http://ubuntuforum.webs.com/proprietarydrivers.htm)