# System doesn't boot after amd 11.9 driver install

Tags: 11.10, boot, ati

Im having a bit of a problem with ubuntu. I just installed amd 11.9 driver from the amd website.

Now the boot is stuck at this image.
[image: boot fail]

How do I resolve the issue without reinstalling Ubuntu?
The computer is running Ubuntu 11.10 64bit with an a6-3400m CPU and a 6520g radeon card.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you access another tty? (press alt+ctrl+f1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had all sorts of fun getting the 11.9 driver installed and working. Even using the "additional drivers" didn't work for me.
I had the same issue you had as well. In the end I followed the following steps after booting into recovery and remounting, then dropping into netroot prompt:

1) [Remove the fglrx](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem%3a_Need_to_purge_-fglrx) and revert configuration:

```
    sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh
    sudo apt-get remove --purge xorg-driver-fglrx fglrx*
    sudo apt-get install --reinstall libgl1-mesa-glx libgl1-mesa-dri
    sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

2) Follow the [manual install](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Natty_Installation_Guide) guide:

```
    sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs fakeroot dh-make debhelper debconf libstdc++6 dkms libqtgui4 wget execstack libelfg0 dh-modaliases
    sudo apt-get install ia32-libs (only if on amd64 as I was)
    sh ./ati-driver-installer-11-9-x86.x86_64.run (choose build deb packages)
    sudo dpkg -i fglrx*.deb
    sudo aticonfig --initial -f
```

3) Reboot.

Comment: That was overkill but it worked like a charm. Even gnome shell is working now (Other than horribly disfigured/skewed horizontal scroll bars and tooltips[sometimes]). Thank you very much. This is the reason I switched to ubuntu. =)

Answer (score 2):

On my Ubuntu 11.10 (Lenovo g770), I  couldn't start the X (LightDM). I tried Catalyst 12.1 drivers. I got some errors about `/usr/lib64`.

So, I created a symlink and it worked.

`ln -s /usr/lib /usr/lib64`

Answer (score 1):

If you can access another terminal (press ctrl+alt+f1 keys) type `sudo sh /usr/share/ati/fglrx-uninstall.sh`.

That is the official driver remover from ATI, after that use the "Additional Drivers" application to install the ubuntu packages.

After you reboot to a clean desktop make sure all the old fglrx packages are gone:

```
sudo apt-get purge fglrx*
```

Remove your xorg.conf

```
sudo rm /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

Reinstall xorg

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall xserver-xorg-core libgl1-mesa-glx:i386 libgl1-mesa-dri:i386 libgl1-mesa-glx:amd64 libgl1-mesa-dri:amd64
```

Configure Xorg

```
sudo dpkg-reconfigure xserver-xorg
```

Reboot:

```
sudo reboot
```

After you get to your desktop again use the "Additional Drivers" program but don't enable the post update ones, use the previous version.

Comment: I ran the command and it did it's thing and I can access the gui fine. Thanks for that. However is there any way to install that driver? 11.9 specifically? I need it to run gnome shell properly.

Answer (score 0):

There is issues with some ATI graphics cards using catalyst 11.9 and Ubuntu 11.10 - see the ubuntuforums thread [here](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?p=11343771)