# Disable ATI Proprietary drivers by command line?

Tags: 11.10, command-line, xorg, ati

I've made the mistake of installing the ATI proprietary driver by command line.

**Steps i took:**

1. Downloaded linux drivers
2. Opened the terminal
3. sh amd..driver.run
4. Followed the steps
5. Rebooted

This has caused my screen to not even load after a fresh install of 11.10 Is there a way to remove of disable  these proprietary drivers by command line?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Boot into recovery mode
2. Remount read/write
3. Enter root shell
4. Go to the location where you downloaded the installer then: `./ati* --uninstall`
5. Reboot:)

---

But, you can also get the drivers working by following the steps above, then follow steps 1 to 3 again and replace step 4 with: `./ati* --install`.

Then type: `aticonfig --initial`

Then reboot.

This is how I got the latest drivers from ati working.

Answer (score 1):

Check [wiki.](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/X/Troubleshooting/FglrxInteferesWithRadeonDriver#Problem%3a_Need_to_purge_-fglrx)

Also [this question.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67065/)