# AMD Switchable Graphics (HP Probook 4530s-specific) - any way to enable?

Tags: 11.10, ati, vgaswitcheroo

I'm proud owner of not-that-expensive, yet powerful laptop (HP Probook 4530s). Being a fan, and every-day user of Ubuntu I was unable a way to use discrete GPU from of my laptop (hd6490), the only way ubuntu worked for me - was to disable switchable graphics in bios, and get latest xorg from xorg edgers ppa.

Question: is there a way to install AMD Catalyst drivers and make discrete GPU provide hardware acceleration, instead of having to use integrated Intel HD3000 GPU?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/questions/99687/switch-gpu-between-intel-and-radeon-hd6490-without-restart) (and the answer linked, that is [this one](https://askubuntu.com/questions/67065/system-doesnt-boot-after-amd-11-9-driver-install)) should solve your problem, installing the latest Ati proprietary driver from their website. There is a step-by-step guide on how to do that.

Comment: Will try this approach a bit later today, thanks for pointing me to this solution.

Comment: Can I switch between graphics cards by this method like it does in Windows ?